# Android setLayoutParams messing up other aligned views

Tags: android

In my Android app, I  have two views A and B which are aligned one on top of the other. I have a `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` in my `onCreateView` method which I use to adjust the height of the top view A at runtime. The top of view B is aligned to the bottom of view A.

```
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =
    (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) topView.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.height = myNewHeight;
topView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

But when I then call `B.getY()` on the bottom view in the same OnGlobalLayoutListener, it returns the wrong value, as if the bottom view B hasn't had its Y position adjusted by the changed height of view A above it.

How can I get B.getY() to return the right value? I've tried various calls like `invalidate()` and `requestLayout()` on the views but it hasn't helped. I'm guessing it's because I'm trying to do all of this inside `OnGlobalLayoutListener`, and the Y position of view B isn't updated until `OnGlobalLayoutListener` has finished.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To retrieve the correct Y value you have to use the [View.OnLayoutChangeListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnLayoutChangeListener) callback:

> Interface definition for a callback to be invoked when the layout
> bounds of a view changes due to layout processing.

So every time the ViewA has changed its height the ViewB will be informed for the Layout changed where you can safely retrieve the new Y position.

Example:

```
View viewA = findViewById(R.id.viewA);
View viewB = findViewById(R.id.viewB);

//add OnLayoutChangeListener to ViewB
viewB.addOnLayoutChangeListener(new View.OnLayoutChangeListener()
{
    @Override
    public void onLayoutChange(View v, int left, int top, int right, int bottom, int oldLeft, int oldTop, int oldRight, int oldBottom)
    {
        //get the new Y of ViewB
        int viewBNewY = (int) v.getY(); //or int viewBNewY = top;
    }
});

//change the height of ViewA
ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams) viewA.getLayoutParams();
layoutParams.height = 400;
viewA.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```